# Making HTTP request using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I've researched numerous articles on this site and still have yet to get a solution that works for me. I keep getting this error “The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method”. Through my research on this site I have found that "Accept" is a restricted column therefore you cannot add. Ive tried various things such as `addwithoutvalidate` and still no luck. I have also read that I can bring in the `WebCollectionClass` and 'modify' the "Accept" column. However I am still a novice at powershell and can greatly use some assistance. I've asked everyone here at work that claims to have powershell knowledge and still no luck. I am trying to make an http request using powershell in order to pull some data. Here is the script:

```
#Decrypt password from DB
$encryptedpwdFromDB = $pass #String retrieved from database

#Decrypt key 
$key= $KeyTrue #Key Array retrieved from database

#Convert the password to plain text
$secPasswd = $encryptedpwdFromDB | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key | ForEach-Object {[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($_))}
#Saves Credentials as a PSCredential object
$username = "haloguest"            
$myCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential( $username,($secPasswd | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force))

#HTTP Request to Rest API
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept", 'application/xml')

$headers.Add("X-UserToken", '00efebdc4f4606001491a50f0310c7716bbefc004b7a1ff4116f13a42e067b76a413414d')
$uri = "https://aaronsdev.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user?sysparm_limit=100000&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $mycreds -OutFile "\\ken-dev-bi002\DVPKicker\users.xml" -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Reusable method at this link instead to make any http call: [Request Rest Reusable Method](https://github.com/HarvestingClouds/PowerShellSamples/blob/master/Scripts/Request-Rest.ps1).

You can directly pass the arguments to the methods. Let me know in comments if you face any issues using this method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As I mentioned I am still a novice. I am assuming I would make changes in lines 53-79. Based on information above can you tell me what to put and where>

Comment: Just include my method in the beginning of your script. Simply copy paste everything from that link at the beginning. Then only keep the lines from your script related to the Credentials. Remove the three lines for headers. Keep the line for populating $uri. Then invoke my function (instead of Invoke-RestMethod) like this:- ***Request-Rest -URL $uri -credentials $myCreds***   
  Please mark as answer if this helps.

Comment: Hello I followed your instructions but I am still getting the same error here is what I did https://github.com/dmoses5/Test2/wiki/Code

Comment: Then this can be a non-PowerShell related issue. Try using Fiddler and perform the same operation via Fiddler with hard-coded credentials and see if you still get the error. Also, try from a different machine. Do check if the URL you are trying to access has any specific requirements and it may be expecting something in the header.